# "Unexpected Error" Trouble When Publishing Token Contract

Tags: gnosis-safe

We have been trying for days to publish our Token Contract using our Gnosis Safe multisig wallet on Ethereum Remix, and running into errors during the publishing step each time.

We have done the following:

- When using Ethereum Remix, we've signed up for and utilizing an
  Infura ID to enable us to use Wallet Connect to connect with Gnosis
  Safe
- We have been using the iOS version of both Gnosis Safe and
  MetaMask (which is where it opens our personal wallets to do the
  first-of-two signing)
- We have failure points at one of these two
  steps, each time:
- 1. During the switch to MetaMask to do the
     signing, it will not pop up the Confirm box to confirm the
     transaction (30% of the time)
- 2. After the MetaMask signing, it
     will not confirm/proceed within Gnosis Safe (or Remix), giving a
     blend of errors all related to "Unexpected Error", requesting us to
     reach out to support (70% of the time)

Is there a best practice and/or a guide around how to do this type of multi-sig transaction properly? Is there a different tool we should use instead of Remix to publish our Token Contract?

Thank you so much and let me know if I can provide any more needed info!

Adam

Comment: If you use hardhat you could look at https://github.com/rmeissner/hardhat-safe-deployer (example: https://github.com/rmeissner/hardhat-safe-deployer-example)

Answer (score 0):

When using Safe with WalletConnect keys, it might be flaky because the communication between apps is using a bridge server, so there might be networking issues. Also, WalletConnect in MetaMask is not very stable. We recommend cleaning the WalletConnect sessions in MetaMask —> Settings —> Experimental from time to time.

If the MetaMask key does not work well for you, I recommend importing your MetaMask private key to the Safe app. It will remove bridge server dependency and will be more stable.

Your contract creation fails because it is not possible to create a new contract by directly using the 0x0 address as a recipient. But it is possible if you use an intermediate contract that would use create2 or create opcodes.

Here you can find such contract https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/libraries/CreateCall.sol

Contract deployments: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-deployments/blob/main/src/assets/v1.3.0/create_call.json

Here you can find a hardhat plugin to deploy it programmatically https://github.com/rmeissner/hardhat-safe-deployer

I hope this information will help you!